# Nemytskii operator defined on space $\ell_2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function. Define operator $$F:\ell_2\to\ell_2, \quad F(x_1,x_2,\ldots)=(f(x_1),f(x_2),\ldots).$$ It is clear that if there exist $a,\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)|\leq a|x|$ for all $x\in(-\delta,\delta)$ then $F$ is well defined (if $x\in\ell_2$ then $F(x)\in\ell_2)$.

Is the converse true, i.e. if $F$ is well defined then there exist $a,\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)|\leq a|x|$ for all $x\in(-\delta,\delta)$ ?

Thanks for any help.